# Saving custom ggplot theme for future files

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, customization

Apologies for being a novice... in R I have a custom ggplot theme that I like to use for a number of different projects (with many separate scripts), but am finding it frustrating needing to copy and paste it over to each script when I have to use them in isolation to avoid frying my laptop.

It might be lazy, but is there a way to save the theme settings so that when I open a new file or create a new script, I can use it without needing to find the code and copy it in again?

This is the shortened version of the theme:

```
    new_roz_theme <- theme_bw() +   
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "gray", size = 1.5), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",
                                  hjust=0.5, size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 10),
        legend.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 10),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour= "white", fill="white")) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank())
```

Thanks so much for any suggestions!
:)

Comment: See https://community.rstudio.com/t/automatically-starting-an-r-script-when-you-open-an-rstudio-project-file/25386/4 and the warning therein. You can probably simplify your theme by using the `base_size`  and `base_family` arguments to `theme_bw`

Comment: You can save R objects using `saveRDS()` and recall them using `readRDS()`.  For example, `saveRDS(new_roz_theme, "new_roz_theme.rds")` to save them to your current working directory and `new_roz_theme <- readRDS("new_roz_theme.rds")` to read them.  Set up directory for your themes, and you will always know where they are.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

iris2 <- iris


## This is not generic version 

iris2 %>%
ggplot()+
geom_jitter(aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Sepal.Length,color=Species))+theme_bw() +   
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "gray", size = 1.5), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",
                                  hjust=0.5, size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 10),
        legend.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 10),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour= "white", fill="white")) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank()) 


## assign the theme to an object

saved_theme <- theme_bw() +   
  theme(panel.border = element_rect(colour = "gray", size = 1.5), 
        panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",
                                  hjust=0.5, size = 12, face = "bold"),
        axis.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 10),
        axis.text.x = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 10),
        axis.text.y = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 10),
        legend.title = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 12),
        legend.text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman",size = 10),
        strip.background = element_rect(colour= "white", fill="white")) +
  theme(strip.background = element_blank(),
        strip.text.x = element_blank()) 

## save it as RDS
saved_theme %>% saveRDS('saved_theme.rds')




#delete the theme object
rm(saved_theme)


## read theme from file

themex <- readRDS('saved_theme.rds')


iris2 %>%
ggplot()+
geom_jitter(aes(x=Sepal.Width,y=Sepal.Length,color=Species))+
themex
```

[image]